# Junit mocking for hashmap having value as multivaluemap

Tags: spring

I have a problem, How to set value for this hashmap and mock it

```
Map <String, MultiValueMap<String, Integer>> idsrcMp = new HashMap<>(3);
```

Comment: Can anyone help me in this issue, plz. With my format as specified above

Comment: Post more code so we can see what the problem is that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "set value and mock it". You want to set values **or** mock it ?

#### You can use the Map / MultiValueMap this way:

```
Map<String, MultiValueMap<String, Integer>> idsrcMp = new HashMap<>(3);
MultiValueMap<String, Integer> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
multiValueMap.put("item", Collections.emptyList()); // insert a List here
idsrcMp.put("first", multiValueMap);
```

#### Using Mocks:

```
Map map = Mockito.mock(Map.class);
MultiValueMap multiValueMap = Mockito.mock(MultiValueMap.class);

Mockito.when(map.get("mapItem")).thenReturn(multiValueMap);
Mockito.when(multiValueMap.get("multimapItem"))
       .thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
```